# D3 : can't call svg.selectAll("text") twice on a same SVG object

Tags: d3.js

I think my understanding of selectAll is wrong,

This jsFiddle should explain the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/maxl/JY4hq/2/

I have create a bar chart like follows :

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
            //etc
```

I add labels

```
        svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(labels)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function(d) {return d})
            // etc
```

then values that get should be displayed at the right end of the bars :

```
        svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
            // etc
```

The problem is that the last addition of texts don't get added to the parent SVG
node. I think my understanding of selectAll is deficient ...

Comment: I don't have time to try and fix the jsfiddle, but I think if you separated the text into two groups it would fix the problem. I think the issue is that right now you are telling D3 to associate append all text according to 1 data set, and then telling it to append all text to another data set. This is contradictory, so I think it's ignoring second dataset. If you broke this into 2 groups it should be able to rightly assign all text (in the group) to a dataset.

Comment: Also, I found this article very helpful in coming to grips with exactly what is going on with the select all declarations: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Comment: The selector "text" is not specific enough. The second time that selector is used, it will select all the existing label text elements and perform a data join with those elements. The common approach is to use a class to make the selector more specific: http://jsfiddle.net/JY4hq/3/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have written a post explaining how selectAll and enter works. It will help in understanding the issue.

Here is the link: http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.com/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html?m=1

If you want a quick fix, the following should work if there are no other elements 
with the class `labels` and class `values` in your html document:

```
    svg.selectAll("text.labels")
       .data(labels)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text(function(d) {return d})
        // etc

    svg.selectAll("text.values")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
        // etc
```

Comment: In all examples I saw so far the `selectAll()` selects by node name only, but it is so much cleaner to have the select function be more specific with a class name like the example above. Wondering why most tutorials do not mention this.